# Android Social Networking App

Tags: java, android, social-networking, ads

I am planning to write a social networking application for Android. I want to learn the architecture for my app . few things i want to know are :
1. Where will i store my data, pictures and information for specific user, administrator data etc.
2. What should be architecture of the application in terms of security , backend, server, request response and what tools can i use. 
3. can i store data on cloud for so many people, if yes then how to start with?
4. how can i show add on my application and earn some money?

Please also suggest some small architecture of existing app or book/article i can refer that not only tells me theoretical concepts but also tells me what tools i need to use except Android, eclipse, java etc

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: You need to rethink what "social networking application" means. "Social", by definition, means connected to multiple other parties. Unless you want P2P social networking that deals with all your network members changing IP address, going in and out of mobile data reception, etc., you're going to need to store your content centrally - i.e. a server or "the cloud". You probably only want to store basic info in your app such as user credentials, and fetch it from the server when needed. You need to decide on server tech, not just Android capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On android, you can store things in a SQLite Database, in something called SharedPreferences, or as a file (jpegs, txt files, etc) at some path.
2. The architecture really depends on what you want the application to do, but generally, try to build a data layer, one that retrieves, saves, and organizes the data and then a user interface layer. I like to keep these two as separate as possible and then have a single bridge from the data to the user interface. In terms of tools you could use, Facebook released Boltz recently so check that out! Here is the link: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android
3. Yes you can, look into using Amazon Web services, I really like them, but there are endless different options.
4. Look into the AdMob libraries.

If you're asking broad questions like these, I would suggest starting with something simpler. Good luck to you!

Comment: Thanks, i think i will go with AWS and use it for backend .

Answer (score 1):

I have some needs just like you. I used to Parse to solve https://parse.com. It's support cloud data storage, push notifications and integration social networking.

It's should be able to help you build your app quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,my requirements are as follows

1. **user management**
2. **video post**
3. **sharing(via Facebook or Twitter)**
4. **comment & like**

Those requirements need backend server to store data.Maintenance costs need to be considered.
For this reason,some of the companies providing cloud services I prefered:

1. **parse**：one backend to rule them all.don’t worry about server management
2. **Titanium ACS**：like parse.offering a fast and easy way to build mobile app.

Those site provide many APIs to help you solve your problem.You can focus on creating a great user experience and forget server maintenance and complex infrastructure.

Also,you can search projects on this site(binpress.com).I find some that meets my requirements.

1. [Instagram Clips](http://www.binpress.com/app/instagram-clips-your-first-android-social-app/1922)
2. [startme](http://www.binpress.com/app/startme-your-ios7-social-network/1683)

For your information.